# Push a file to my Android device in Appium

Tags: android, appium

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm trying to write Appium tests for my Android device. Now I need to transfer an image file to my Android device (in order to upload it in a form). However, when using the pushFile() command from the AppiumDriver class I get the following error:

```
> error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: 404 - unknown command: session/f4f13b14a94c0d39d575ff326ebea6c1/appium/device/push_file
```

Now, after searching the internet I found that this is just another alias for "It has not yet been implemented". Isn't there another way to push a file? Or a way to push a file manually? By doing a raw adb command for instance?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What language are you using to write your scripts? It's possible that you're on too old version of the appium client or then this feature simply isn't implemented yet for that language.
Also, what version of Appium are you using?

Comment: Yea I was, already fixed by updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update to Appium 1.5. Appium 1.4 doesn't support it apparently.